# Can't upload image using fileinput kartik yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I want to update image using fileinput kartik in yii2. It is success when create, but not when update. This is my view.php

```
<?= $form->field($bukuForm, 'gambar_buku', ['labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2']])->label('Gambar')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
        'options' => ['multiple' => false],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            // 'previewFileType' => 'image',
            'allowedFileExtensions' => ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'],
            'showUpload' => false,
            'initialPreview' => [
                Html::img(\Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->baseUrl . '/web/uploads/images/bahanpustaka/' . $bukuForm->gambar_buku, ['width' => 200, 'height' => 250, 'class' => 'file-preview-image'])
            ],
            'initialCaption' => $bukuForm->gambar_buku,
        ],
        'id' => 'field_gambar',
    ])->hint('File: .png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif'); ?>
```

And this is my controller.php

```
if ($bukuForm->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $bukuForm->gambar_buku = UploadedFile::getInstance($bukuForm, 'gambar_buku');
            echo $bukuForm->gambar_buku;
            die();
```

When I run the update function, the result of gambar_buku is NULL.
This is the image when I click update button.
[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: did you add enctype to form options? add this to form options 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data"

Comment: Yes, I have added it